# Check the validity of a loaded file after an AJAX request, how to warn the client?

Tags: php, ajax, upload, xmlhttprequest

I upload a file using the XMLHttpRequest(). It works fine. I check the size of that file on the server side (using php) and then if the file **is too big I want to warn my client in order to display a message** saying "The file is too big".
How can I do it, is this possible ?!

Comment: You just need to return a [400 Bad request status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), and in your [JS catch the non 20X response](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+ajax.failure)...

Comment: The way I normally would approach this would be to upload the file via AJAX and return a JSON response detailing the status. On error I would return a status code with an error message detailing that the file is too big and use Javascript to display that error.